# what to do if my npm frank package is not working?

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I'm having trouble getting the franc npm package to work in my Node.js project. I have created a package.json file and installed the franc package, but when I try to use it with require("franc"), I get an error. It's strange because other packages like colors work just fine.

Can anyone offer any insight into what might be causing this issue and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance for your help.

1step
i have created new empty directory
2 step
i have created package.JSON
3 step
i have downloaded the package
4 step
i created index.js
5 step
i required : const franc = ("franc") and console.log(franc("Voici un court texte en français"))
6 step
i tryed to run node index.js and i am keep getting errors
TypeError: franc is not a function
at Object. ←[90m(C:\Users\nursu\Goat\langGuesser\←[39mindex.js:2:13←[90m)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47←[39m

Node.js v19.9.0

Answer (score 0):

As it is [mentioned](https://www.npmjs.com/package/franc#:%7E:text=This%20package%20is%20ESM%20only.%20In%20Node.js%20(version%2014.14%2B%2C%2016.0%2B)%2C%20install%20with%20npm%3A) on npm

> This package is ESM only. In Node.js (version 14.14+, 16.0+), install
> with npm:
> https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

Meaning you have to use import/export instead of require/module.exports

Also make sure to specify `"type": "module"` in your package.json.